# Update UI During Thread (Windows Form, C#)

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now, and I seem to not be the only one. There are many threads on this topic, however, none have seemed to work for me. Hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

SUMMARY: I have created a windows form with many controls. The user can set these controls, then "start" a test. This triggers a thread so I can still access the windows form during the test (which can last for weeks). I want to update the UI during this thread, however, I have yet to figure out how to do that.

I have written a very small windows form application, thinking that it would be easier to use this to explain my issue, then I can fix my larger problem using the advice given here.

Here is the code of my smaller program that presently does not compile

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => startNewThread());
            thread.Start();
        }

        public static void startNewThread()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                string text = string.Format("Time: [{0}]", i);
                label1.Invoke((Action)delegate { label1.Text = text; });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use advice given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937974/update-label-on-windows-form-from-non-ui-thread) thread by @JaredPar, but I was unable to get it to work for me. However, the intent would be to click the button, go to the thread, update the label inside the thread. Like I said, I cannot compile yet, and receive the following error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.label1'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I apologize for my lack of knowledge, as I assume this is completely basic. I'm learning everyday.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `public static void startNewThread()` cannot be static if you want to access label1. Change it to `public void startNewThread()`

Comment: Wow! It seriously was that simple. At least for now. We'll see what other things this screws up, but that seems to work for now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to solve your issue:

1. Your thread function cannot be static.
2. Use this.Invoke instead of Label.Invoke.

However, if you always want to update your UI on a regular basis and on a consistent amount of time, A better solution is to use System.Windows.Timer which is a timer that runs on the main UI Thread and ticks by the interval you initialize it with. Then you won't have to use Invoke methods.

Have a look here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with UI threads can be tricky. Here's a tip that has been handy for me. Add the following extension method to your project.

```
public static class WindowsFormsControlExtensions
{
    public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        control.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

You can use the extension when adding methods in your form class as follows. The `this` keyword will be referencing the form and the containing code will be executed on the thread containing the form's handle.

```
public void SetLabel(string text)
{
    this.Invoke(() =>
    {
        if (label1 != null)
            label1.Text = text;
    });
}
```